# Detecting when a child outside of element gets focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, focus

Here's the basic setup: I have a thin bar at the top of a website containing accessibility-related links. If javascript is enabled, this is hidden (negative margin). However, I would like to show the bar whenever a user tabs through the links. Here's what I'm doing:

```
var bar = $("#bar");
bar.find("a").on("focus", function(){
    if(bar.css("margin-top") == "-50px"){
        bar.animate({ marginTop: 0 }, 250);
    }
});
```

That works. However, when it comes to closing this bar it gets a bit tricky. If I bind a `blur` event to the `a`, it will hide when I tab through **each** link. I want to hide it only when **all** links are blurred.

I would like to do this:

```
bar.find("a").on("blur", function(){
    // If no links inside #bar have focus now:
    bar.animate({ marginTop: -50 }, 250);
});
```

How?

Comment: it was yesterday that i was looking for a way to find out which element has current focus. good luck with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `blur` event fires **before** the `focus` event fires, you should set a timeout in the `blur` event, and cancel it in the `focus` event.

```
(function () {

    var bar = $("#bar");
    var timeout;

    bar.find("a").on("focus", function(){
        clearTimeout(timeout);

        if(bar.css("margin-top") == "-50px"){
            bar.animate({ marginTop: 0 }, 250);
        }
    });

    bar.find("a").on("blur", function(){
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            // If no links inside #bar have focus now:
            bar.animate({ marginTop: -50 }, 250);
        }, 1);
    });

}());
```

Comment: Great! Did not realise blur fires before focus, so your answer was picked (although the answer by @jAndy also worked perfectly). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do it like so:

```
bar.find("a").on("blur", function() {    
    setTimeout(function() { 
        if( $('a:focus').length === 0 ) {
            // If no links inside #bar have focus now:
            bar.animate({ marginTop: -50 }, 250);
        }
    }, 15);
});
```

This one queries for all `anchors` which might have a focus, if the `.length` is zero, we should know that we can hide that bar now. I didn't test that code yet, please let me know.

See http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/e4PaN/

Comment: This worked perfectly. I had tried doing a `length` check for `a:focus`, but did not take into account the fact that blur fires before focus events (as answer by @Matt below). Thanks!